# using wpf animation techniques to change an object properties - several at once

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, dependency-properties

I have an class

```
public class Point : Geometry, IComparable<Point>  
{
    private bool _IsEmpty = false;
    private double _X;
    private double _Y;
    (etc..)
}
```

which represents the centre of an object. I want to animate the object with something like a `TransformTranslate`.

I know I can kick off two seperate animations (one for X, one for Y), but then if I do a refresh()/redraw() whenever the centre changes, I get two calls (one for each of x, y).

Can I hijack the animation system to animate an object (my `Point` object)? By this I mean giving an initial state of x, y; then a final one and letting the animation system take care of the interpolation.

**Or**, do I just code it up myself with a timer, etc..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [PointAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimation.aspx) class that should solve your problem.

If you can't use the PointAnimation you could create two double animations and keep them in a single storyboard that controls (starts/stops) them.

Also: I'd stay away from refreshing/redrawing by hand. WPF will do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't even know about the PointAnimation..
I had to set up a DependencyProperty on my object so that I could animate it, but it works now :)